# Stop / abort a class-loop thread, C#

Tags: c#

I've started a thread in c#, but I want to be able to abort it and don't really know how to.

```
private void createThread(){
     Thread threadDraw = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myMethod /*Starts a class which loops for a long time*/ ));
     threadDraw.Start();
     if(myBool == false) {theadDraw.Abort();}
}
```

`myMethod` is starting a class that runs on a loop. The thing is, I want to be able to stop the loop with a keypress (in my case space). Currently, I've tried with

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    /* Checks space press, if space press: make myBool = false */
}
```

It changes myBool into false and the method itself works.

The problem here is, `createThread()` doesn't constantly check if `myBool` is false, and thereby doesn't stop.

I've also tried

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    /*checks for spacepress, then {threadDraw.Abort()} */
}
```

but it doesn't work either, I have tried replacing private with public on `createThread` but still, doesn't work.

Additionally, I've been thinking about creating a `KeyDown()`-method inside of the class and have a *break;* in the loop but either I'm doing something wrong (likely) or it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill a thread instantly in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327102/how-to-kill-a-thread-instantly-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `if(myBool == false) {theadDraw.Abort();}` isn't working because you're checking this once, immediately after the thread starts. And it isn't ever checked again (`threadDate.Start()'` isn't a blocking call).

But, NET Framework contains the `CancellationToken` concept which is used to cancel asynchronous code.

```cs
// Step 1, create a cancellation token:
CancellationTokenSource cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

// Step 2, reference the token from inside your thread
void ThreadStartMethod() {
   while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested) {
      // Do work ...
   }
}

// Step 3, cancel the token when you need to
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
       cancel.Cancel();
}
```

*Note: make sure you re-create the cancellation token whenever you start the thread*

Comment: I recently tried with cancellation-token, but due to the loop being inside of the class it didn't work then. Although I've now moved the loop outside the class, and thereby I am now able to cancel it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried replacing private with public on createThread but still, doesn't work.

That will only change the visibility of the method, not the working of the method.

A thread executes the code only once. So likely your `myMethod` has a loop that prevents it from being terminated. The [`Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netcore-3.1) way of terminating the threads is not graceful (See the **Remarks** section of the documentation). You already have a conditional variable in your code, `myBool`, you can use it inside the `myMethod` to gracefully exit the loop and let the thread terminate itself.

```
void myMethod() {
    while (myBool && myLogic) { // if myBool is false, short-circuit and leave
        // thread code here.
    }
}
```

This will help the thread know when to stop by getting out of the loop. Oh, and this approach requires your first `Form1_KeyDown` method where you set the `myBool` value.

Note that you do not need to use a `while`, you can use any other iterative structure like `do...while` or a `for` loop as well. The logic is to finish the loop as soon as `myBool` becomes false. Yes, a `break` will work too. :-)

Now, back to your statement:

> I want to be able to abort it

If you want the threat to abort right away, then my approach will not work since it requires a conditional check before loop execution. So, you might expect a delay of few microseconds — if your business requires accuracy of microseconds then forcing a thread to shut down is needed with `Abort`.